# How list differ from map?

Tags: java

In java, List and Map are using in collections. But i couldn't understand at which situations we should use List and which time use Map. What is the major difference between both of them?

Comment: Way to get a skeet answer!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Now would be a good time to read the [Java collections tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) - but fundamentally, a list is an ordered sequence of elements which you can access by index, and a map is a *usually unordered* mapping from keys to values. (Some maps preserve insertion order, but that's implementation-specific.)

It's *usually* fairly obvious when you want a key/value mapping and when you just want a collection of elements. It becomes less clear if the key is *part of* the value, but you want to be able to get at an item by that key efficiently. That's still a good use case for a map, even though in *some* senses you don't have a separate collection of keys.

There's also `Set`, which is a (usually unordered) collection of *distinct* elements.

Answer (score 5):

[Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is for `Key:Value` pair kind of data.for instance if you want to map student roll numbers to their names.

[List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is for simple ordered collection of elements which allow duplicates.
for instance to represent list of student names.

Answer (score 1):

Map Interface
A Map cares about unique identifiers. You map a unique key (the ID) to a specific
value, where both the key and the value are, of course, objects. 
The Map implementations let you do things like search for a
value based on the key, ask for a collection of just the values, or ask for a collection
of just the keys. Like Sets, Maps rely on the equals() method to determine whether
two keys are the same or different.

List Interface
A List cares about the index. The one thing that List has that non-lists don't have
is a set of methods related to the index. Those key methods include things like
get(int index), indexOf(Object o), add(int index, Object obj), and so
on. All three List implementations are ordered by index position—a position that
you determine either by setting an object at a specific index or by adding it without
specifying position, in which case the object is added to the end.

Answer (score 1):

list is a linked list, where every object is connected to the next one via pointers. the time it takes to insert a new object to the list is O(1) but the rest of operations on it take longer.

the good thing about it is that it takes exactly the amount of memory you need and not even on byte more than that.

Maps are a data structure that has an array and each entry to the array is calculated with a `hashFunction(key)` that calculates the location according to the key. almost every operation in a Map taks O(1) (except inserting when there are 2 identical keys) but the space complexity is fairly large.

for more reading try wikipedia's [HashMap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) and [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)

Comment: HashMap and LinkedList are implementations of the Map and List interface, they are only one specific case of those collections.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet, you are correct, but the idea is what's important. understanding the difference between hashmap and linkedlist is the basis of understanfing the difference between MAP and LIST

Answer (score 1):

HashList is a data structure storing objects in a hash table and a list.it is a combination of hashmap and doubly linked list. acess will be faster. HashMap is hash table implementation of map interface it is same as HashTable except that it is unsynchronized and allow null values.     List is an ordered collection and it allow nulls and duplicates in it. positional acess is possible.                                                       Set is a collection that doesn't allow duplicates, it may allow at most one null element. same as our mathematical set.

Answer (score 0):

`List` is just an ordered collectiom(a sequence). Check this [list documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) .You can access elements by their integer index (position in the list), and search for elements in the list.
Also lists allow duplicate elements and multiple NULL elements.

`Map` is an object that maps the values to the keys. Check this [map documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html). A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

Answer (score 0):

```
List - This datastructure is used to contain list of elements. 
       In case you need list of elements and the list may contain duplicate values, 
       then you have to use List.

Map - It contains data as key value pair. When you have to store data 
      in key value pair,so that latter you can retrieve data using the key,
      you have to use Map data structure.
```

List implementation - **ArrayList, LinkedList**
Map implementation - **HashMap, TreeMap**

In comparison `HashMap` to `ArrayList` - 
A hash map is the fastest data structure if you want to get all nodes for a page. The list of nodes can be fetched in constant time (O(1)) while with lists the time is O(n) (n=number of pages, faster on sorted lists but never getting near O(1))